# Combine multiple arrays and covert to string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two fields

- first_name
- last_name

Both are arrays.

> I would like to combine the arrays and covert to a human readable
> string. How can I achieve this?

Here is where I'm at:

```
        $firstName = $this->state['first_name'];
        $lastName = $this->state['last_name'];

        $firstLastName = array_combine($firstName , $lastName);

/* $firstLastName outputs:
   array:2 [▼
     "John" => "Doe"
     "Jane" => "Doe"
   ]
 */


        $string = implode(', ', $firstLastName);

        dd($string);

// $string outputs:
//"Doe, Doe" 
//Only getting the last names
```

How can I get this to output `John Doe, Jane Doe`?

Comment: `$firstLastName = array_map(function($f, $l) { return $f.' '.$l;}, $firstName, $lstName);`

Comment: @splash58 That worked great. Put it as an answer so I can close this. Thanks!

Comment: Very well. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_map to combine arrays

```
    $firstName = $this->state['first_name'];
    $lastName = $this->state['last_name'];
    $firstLastName = array_map(function($f, $l) { return $f.' '.$l;}, $firstName, $lastName);
```

Comment: Small typo here too. `return $f.' '$l;}` forgot the `.`  in front of `$l;` in the return.

Answer (score 1):

well something like this:

```
$res = [];
for($firstLastName as $k => $v){
   $res[] = "{$k} {$v}";
}
$string = implode(', ', $res);
```

or without joining them before:

```
$firstLastName = array_map(
    function($name, $last){ 
         return "{$name} {$last}";
    },
    $this->state['first_name'],
    $this->state['last_name']
);
```